# SQL Server 2012 , create SSIS job not working

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis, sql-server-2012, jobs

I create an SSIS package with VS 2013 SSDT-bi, I try to create a job in SQL Server 2012:

I add my package under Integration Services Catalogs, when I want to validate it says :

> Package error : Pacakge migration from version 8 to version 6 failed with error 0xC001700A
>   The version number in the package is not valid. the version number cannot be greater than current version number

And when I try to create a new job it says :

> The package failed to load due to error 0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors. This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails.

I Googled and I found that VS 2013 SSDT-bi starts working with SQL Server 2014.
I want to know if there is a workaround for my issue or I have to download VS2012 and re-create my package ?

Comment: As stated [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674919.aspx) VS2013 works with `SQL Server 2012`. Did you set the `Target server` correctly in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did succeed in tricking it to work (changing the project/package XML). However, i would never recommend that, since it's gonna stop working at some point and give you further headaches.

Download VS 2012 SSDT (you'll probably need VS2012 shell as well), open packages there and redeploy.

EDIT: spelling :(